# Hostable gallery software

Tags: javascript, html, php, css, jquery

I need a gallery that I can host locally to display various galleries, as typical of photographers: a section for weddings, another for seniors, etc.

Although I know what I'm looking for and it's quite common, I'm not finding any via google.

I would be more happy if those groups further divide, with thumbnails, into sub groups.

For example, you go to my home page and at the top or on the side, you see: Seniors, Groups, etc. When you click one of those, the main content area shows thumbnails with more sections: Amy, Joann, Danielle, etc.

When you click one of those, you're presented with a set of images which if you click one, will enlarge. Similar to Flickr or Pixieset is much preferred, but even a simple left-right slider would work.

Very important, however: I don't want to manually resize and create matching names for my images; I'd like to move them, and let the script do the dirty work for me.

Suggestions?

Comment: Free or Paid? A web service or a JavaScript Library?

Comment: @Tom Free and paid (One Time Payment - nothing recurring.)  - will consider both. Just looking for a .zip containing the php/js, etc. files that I can implement into an existing site.

Comment: Should galleries be visible by anyone on the internet? Do you need authentication/permissions? Only one admin?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I don't need any admins, simple drop png into folder would work fine. No login/hidden images.

Answer (score 1):

If you do your own website hosting, how about coppermine?

http://coppermine-gallery.net/

I initially used it over a decade ago, and it's still very well supported and has lots of new innovations.

It creates the thumbnails automatically, and lets you have a large variety of different folders and permissions for galleries.

The gallery is very extensible, and has lots of plug-ins you can install:
http://coppermine-gallery.net/plugins.php?cpg_version=5

Here's a link to the site demo:
http://coppermine-gallery.net/demo/cpg15x/

Here's a link to some free 3rd party themes:
https://www.siteground.com/coppermine-hosting/coppermine-themes.htm

Comment: From the demo, it doesn't aesthetically implement very well - it looks like a forum.

Comment: not at all, I've never used any of the forum stuff.  one moment, let me find you some links to examples using coppermine.  Check-out their site demo: http://coppermine-gallery.net/demo/cpg15x/